# javascript Firebase database get values grouped

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need these values in a row, but I don't want them reply if its already in div.

My try is here. I try to build an array and put these values from firebase to here, but still I can't see in html.

```
  var fruits = [];
  var fetchPostsleft = function(postsRef, sectionElement,fruits) {
    postsRef .orderByChild('timeStamp').on('child_added', function(data) {
        console.log(data.val());
      var author = data.val().senderName;


        var containerElement2 = sectionElement.getElementsByClassName('posts-containerleft')[0];

        fruits.push(data.val().senderName);  
        console.log(fruits.length);


   });

  };


    fetchPostsleft(topUserPostsRef, topUserPostsSectionleft,fruits);
var fLen = fruits.length;
        console.log(fruits.length);

for (var i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
   // text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
   topUserPostsSectionleft.getElementsByClassName('posts-containerleft')[0].insertBefore( createheaders(fruits[i], ""),
   topUserPostsSectionleft.getElementsByClassName('posts-containerleft')[0].firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. This means that by the time your looping over the array, it hasn't been populated yet. It's easiest to see this by replacing most of the code with a few log statements:

```
console.log("Before query");
postsRef.orderByChild('timeStamp').on('child_added', function(data) {
    console.log("In child_added");
});
console.log("After query");
```

If you run this snippet, the logging will be:

> Before query
>
> After query
>
> In child_added

This is probably not the order you expected, since it's different from the order the log statements are in your code. This is because the data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously and the rest of your code continues while it's loading.

It's slightly easier to see if you turn the callback into a separate function:

```
function onChildAdded(data) {
    console.log("In child_added");
});

console.log("Before query");
postsRef.orderByChild('timeStamp').on('child_added', onChildAdded);
console.log("After query");
```

Now you can more easily see that the first few lines just *declare* the `onChildAdded` function. They don't run it yet. And we're just passing that function *in* to the query, so that the query can call `onChildAdded` whenever it gets the data.

This is the most common pitfall of web programming with remote servers. But since most of the modern web is based on such asynchronous APIs, you will have to learn it.

One way I've found that works is to reframe your problem. Your current code is based on "first fetch the posts, then add them to the HTML". But in asynchronous programming it's better to think "start fetching the posts. When we get them, add them to the HTML". This translates into the following code:

```
function fetchPostsleft(postsRef, sectionElement) {
  postsRef.orderByChild('timeStamp').on('child_added', function(data) {
    var author = data.val().senderName;
    topUserPostsSectionleft.getElementsByClassName('posts-containerleft')[0].insertBefore(createheaders(author, ""),
  });
};

fetchPostsleft(topUserPostsRef, topUserPostsSectionleft);
```

Now all the code that needs the new data is *inside* the callback, so it's only run when the snapshot is actually available.